# .NET - Passing Enum with Attribute Through WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, attributes, enums

Does anyone know if it is possible to serialize and pass an enum through WCF with its associated attributes?

For example:

```
public enum Dog
{
    [Description("German Shepard")]
    GERMAN_SHEPARD = 1,
    [Description("Labrador Retriever")]
    LABRADOR_RETRIEVER = 2
}
```

I then want to pass an instance of this enum as the return value of a method exposed via WCF. When the calling code uses "Add Service Reference" it should be able to reconstruct the Description attribute.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up your enum(s) and other types to be transported into a shared assembly. Then, instead of using the "Add Service Reference", you can use the [`/r` flag along with `svcutil` to generate your service proxy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/10/09/reusing-types-in-referenced-assemblies-with-svcutil-s-r-switch.aspx).

Your client application should then reference the enum from the shared assembly instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to mark the enum with the [DataContract and EnumMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx) attributes so the WSDL with contain appropriate values.